# How to test if a field is hidden or displayed on the webpage using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to test if a field is hidden or displayed on the webpage using selenium webdriver?

Ex: A page has three sections and filled with same name `x` which is available in first section and third section of the page. I want to validate whether `x` is displayed or hidden in last section/form/table of the page.

Answer (score 0):

First get the xpath/css, which ever you use, of the element by making it visible. Check the element if exists using selenium web driver size() method
Hope this should work

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this. It really depends on how you write your selector. You can directly point to the `x` of the last section/form etc. and use a simple if condition to verify the element displayed or not. The attachments [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXQwS.jpg) will help you understand the pattern of selector you need.

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium IWebElement type does have a Displayed property.

Did you try retrieving the element and checking that property?

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Displayed.htm